# Wscript make proccess not run on background or wait while finishes

Tags: vbscript, wsh

Scenario: We have some scheduled jobs (Control-M) running many proccesses and some of them execute a .VBS file (with parameters) that reads the configuration from an XML file and sends it to a company's software that interprets it and loads data onto tables.

I need help with the VBS file, that as stated above, only gets the instructions from the XML and send it to the software with these steps (also, logs each step):

1. Finds the XML;
2. Creates an object to login the software (with XML parameters);

   ```
   Dim object 
   Set object = CreateObject("service.location.id")
   ```
3. Login into the Database (with XML parameters);

   ```
   object.Login("DATABASE_NAME")
   ```
4. Select which Data base (XML...);

   ```
   object.SelectDatabase("DATABASE_NAME")
   ```
5. Sends command to start load proccess

   ```
   object.LoadRepositoryTable(XML)
   ```

The problem is that since the default interpreter is `wscript`, when executing the script, it runs on the background and the Job Scheduler thinks it finished executing and starts the next job.

Executing the script on CMD, if I start it as `cscript SCRIPT.vbs` it waits for the whole load proccess to finish (it doesn't run on background), and I want to do this when running as `wscript` - because since there are many jobs, editing how they calls the script is not an option right now. This includes creating an .bat file that calls the `SCRIPT.vbs` as `cscript`.

I also tried searching on "how to run another .vbs file inside a VB Script" to run as `cscript`, but didn't manage to make it work.

What can I do?

Is there a way to make `wscript` wait for the load?

Is there a way to call a .vbs in the same folder (without sending it as parameter) while passing 2 arguments?

Another option I'm not seeing?

**Edit:** Here is what I've come to so far, but I'm getting "expected end of statement".

```
Dim objShell
Dim arg_dir 
arg_dir = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
Dim arg_xml 
arg_xml = Wscript.Arguments.Item(1)
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

objShell.Run "cmd /k cscript ""C:\Folder\Scripts\SCRIPT.vbs" &" "& arg_dir &" "& arg_xml"", 1, True
```

Answer (score 1):

`cscript` is the solution for your problem. Either have your scheduler run each VBScript with `cscript.exe`, or (if that isn't possible for some reason) make `cscript` the default script host by running

```
wscript.exe //h:cscript
```

once as an administrator.

The script you have cobbled together won't resolve your problem, even if you fixed the syntax error in the last line, because as long as you run it with `wscript.exe` it will still return immediately. It doesn't matter that the code in that script is running other scripts synchronously as long as all of that is happening in the background.